# Usage of the below query

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

```
public ClientApp_Detail GetHomeDetbyClientID_AppID(string clientid, long appId)
{
    ClientApp_Detail sp = null;

    using (HelpDeskDataContext HDDC = Conn.GetContext())
    {

        sp = (from st in HDDC.ClientApp_Details where  st.ClientID == clientid && st.AppID == appId && st.IsDeleted != true select st).FirstOrDefault();

    }

    return sp;
}
```

As I am a beginner to .NET, I am unable to understand the use of the above query and why it is declared as from st in.  Please explain the usage of such type query and what is returning to sp(example) variable.

Comment: Look for LINQ tutorials. Above is query syntax.

Comment: You need to have a look on `LINQ` tutorial.

Comment: This is a linq query. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19154/Understanding-LINQ-C

Comment: And please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask Asking the right way will get (more) useful answers.

Comment: I'd also look at the [Microsoft Naming Guidelines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/xzf533w0%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

```
from st in HDDC.ClientApp_Details
```

is something like

```
foreach(var st in HDDC.ClientApp_Details)
```

Than it filters by following critiria

```
st.ClientID == clientid && st.AppID == appId && st.IsDeleted != true select st
```

And last

```
FirstOrDefault();
```

will return first elemant or default value (default(T)) if nothing matched.

P.S. As it was already told take a look into LINQ tutorials. It's very simple. 
Or you can download [LinqPad](http://www.linqpad.net/). LINQ sampels are included and probably it's the best way to play with LINQ.

Comment: _"`from st in` can be translated to `foreach`"_ - no, it can't. I understand it's a simplification, but it's not exactly correct. Linq is a C# language construct that gets translated to lazily-evaluated `System.Linq` statements.

Comment: @CodeCaster I meant it can be read (for user) as it. Thank you for the note.

Answer (score -1):

Here HelpDeskDataContext is a entity framework context.

```
(from st in HDDC.ClientApp_Details where  st.ClientID == clientid && st.AppID == appId && st.IsDeleted != true select st).FirstOrDefault();
```

The above statement is a LINQ query where **ClientApp_Details** is an Entity of the HelpDeskDataContext.

It is like a sql query---

```
select * from ClientApp_Details where st.ClientID==clientid && st.AppID == appId && st.IsDeleted != true
```

`FirstOrDefault()` has been used if the does not match the criteria then it will return a default value.

Comment: This should be a comment!